# mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, in some column selected

Tags: php, select, mysqli

I'm trying to select all of my column and it works perfectly with this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM employee";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($employee = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    # code...
    print (json_encode($employee));
}
```

and I also succeed select some of my column using this code

```
$query = "SELECT ID, NAME, LAT FROM employee";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

but I failed when I try to select LONG column, it said that

> `mysqli_fetch_array()` expects parameter 1 to be `mysqli_result`

It just show when I select LONG column, but it works well if I select another column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"But i failed when i try to select LONG column"*

That's because `LONG` is a MySQL reserved word.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Either wrap it in backticks, or choose another word for it.

I.e.:

```
$query = "SELECT ID, NAME, `LONG` FROM employee";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT ID, NAME, LAT, `LONG` FROM employee";
```

Comment: You need to slow down haha, you're beating us all!

Comment: @Darren I switched to my other pair of glasses ;-)

Comment: @EdCottrell Thanks Ed, much appreciated. Will +1 yours too, since we weren't that far apart. We were writing the same answer at approximately the same time.

Comment: @Darren You could say ;-) Just not a young "thug" anymore lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- HAHAHA age is just a number. You'll just be considered an OG ;-)

Comment: @Darren I can still "ride" pretty good. Now to get me another `H-D`, still have all my old gear. Like an OG on a H.O.G. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I found your [search engine](http://www.gizoogle.net/index.php?search=Real+OG&se=Gizoogle+Dis+Shiznit)

Answer (score 2):

`LONG` is [a MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). So, your query is resulting in syntax errors when you run `mysqli_query()`. To get around that problem, put it in backticks, like this:

```
$query = "SELECT ID, NAME, LAT, `LONG` FROM employee";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```